# What are the alternatives to install electron?

Tags: node.js, electron

I was trying to install electron by using command `npm install electron --save-dev` but while `Downloading electron-v8.2.3-win32-x64.zip` it was too slow to complete and stuck on 1-2% every times. So what are the ways to solve this problem?

node version: `v12.13.1`

npm version: `6.12.1`

Comment: You can try again after some time.

Comment: `npm install --verbose electron` try this. read this https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/installation#mirror